# valueUpdate events are applied on multiple viewmodel knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I'm newbie to knockoutjs. I Have two form which share the same model. I'm trying to validate some inputs etc. the form have similar inputs fields but they have different ids. The Problem is when i type something in the zipcode of the first form, the result appears in the second form always. Is there something that i can do?

**http://jsfiddle.net/gZC5k/3208/**

```
<form id="c1"method="post" action="" >
<input name="zipcode" type="text" id="zipcode" data-bind="value: zipcode, valueUpdate: ['keyup', 'blur']" >
</form>

<form id="c2" method="post" action="">
<input name="zipcode" type="text" id="zipcode"  data-bind="value: zipcode, valueUpdate: ['keyup', 'blur']">
</form>

var Contact = function(id) {
    var self = this;
    ko.validation.rules['mustEqual'] = {
        async: true,
        validator: function (val, otherVal, callback) {
            $(id).append("result");
        },
        message: 'The field must equal {0}'
    };

    ko.validation.registerExtenders();
    self.zipcode = ko.observable(12).extend({ mustEqual: 5 });

}       
ko.applyBindings(new Contact(document.getElementById("c1")),document.getElementById("c1"));
ko.applyBindings(new Contact(document.getElementById("c2")), document.getElementById("c2"));
```

Comment: What are you trying to validate? are you trying to validate if the zipcode entered equals to a certain constant number .. ?

Comment: this is not my problem, check the link of jsfiddle and u will get the problem. When i type in the first input field, it shows me the message in the second. but i wanna it in the first. So when i typ something wrong in the first input [first form] i wanna get the message in the first form. the same for the second input

Comment: a couple of problems there ... in your code the validator, should point to a callback method that returns true or false indicating if a validation has failed or not. you are adding DOM manipulation there. another thing ... the  validator registration is supposed to be a global thing you are adding it in your view model definition ... making the framework register is everytime you instantiate a viewmodel  not sure if this helps .. http://jsfiddle.net/ppcoj20n/2/

Comment: it looks very good, i think that the problem is the validator snippet code. I should write out of the model view.right? if yes can you explain me why should i do?

Comment: Why did you remove the  "async: true", i need it because im making some ajax call which need to be "async:true"

Answer (score 2):

While executing this line

```
ko.applyBindings(new Contact(document.getElementById("c2")), document.getElementById("c2"));
```

Your view model overrides the old `c1` validation rule with `c2` form reference, thus always executing the last registered validator, which in your case is `c2`. If you switch the statements order as

```
ko.applyBindings(new Contact(document.getElementById("c2")), document.getElementById("c2"));
ko.applyBindings(new Contact(document.getElementById("c1")), document.getElementById("c1"));
```

you will see it will append with `form#c1` then. So move you rules registration outside your view model.

Also if you are setting `async` flag to `true` then you should use `callback` function. Something like

```
validator: function (val, otherVal,callback) {
        callback(val == otherVal); 
        //$(id).append("result");
    },
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/qea0f31d/1/)